# BeginAnimation() permanently freezes view; unable to see changes after reassigning property value directly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm animating the transform property of a `Grid` panel like this:

```
    translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim);
```

Later, when I try to assign a new value to `translateTransform`, I get no visual feedback. However, I do notice that my if-statements branch as expected.

```
    // view not rendered if I call BeginAnimate() any instance before this assignment:
    translateTransform.Y = myNewValue;
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
I needed to call:

```
    translateTransform.ApplyAnimationClock(TranslateTransform.YProperty, null);
```

to dissociate animations from the property before assigning the new value.